# How to get / show data in form when using Nativescript

Tags: angular, local-storage, nativescript

I have 2 component, in first I have a form that add data in local storage.

{
"wifi": "Ttt",
"pass": "Hhh",
"wireless": "1"
}

1. In second component I want to show data in form like in [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXcO3.png) and 2, I want to show data in HomeComponent.

Demo in Playground

https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=4oyZnk

Comment: Please be more specific, what exactly you the issue you are facing here? Is it you are not sure how to pass data between components / it's about loading the data in the form?

Comment: Yes, I save data in local storage, these data I want to display in form, and in home component

Comment: I think this is nothing very much specific to NativeScript. Simply use an Angular service that can hold data for you, same could be injected in any component you want in order to share the data.

Comment: Can you write something for me please?

Comment: Just checkout the angular hello world template, that's a good example for sharing data via services.